# Miracle Fruit grow rate

Tags: growth

How long does a Miracle Fruit Tree (Synsepalum dulcificum) take to grow to (say) 2 feet?

I've just got one that's 5 inches tall and has 6 leaves and was wondering (1) how long it would take to grow to a reasonable size and (2) how long will it take before I see fruit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's slow growing, and will take 3-4 years to reach 2 feet, depending on conditions, at which point it should start producing some fruit. Bear in mind if likes a soil ph between 4.5 and 6, is best watered with rainwater (not tap water) and should never be exposed to temperatures of 50 deg. F or below. It likes to be kept at 70-80 deg F, with high humidity, around 80%. Dappled sunlight is best, as much as anything to stop the plant getting too dry.